# Adding Map to collection of maps

Tags: java

I have collection of maps.

```
Collection<Map<String,Object>> xyz = (Collection<Map<String,Object>>) someMethod();
xyz.add(new HashMap<>());
```

If I try to add another map to this collection it gives me run time exception as

UnsupportedOperation.

What can be done?

Comment: someMethod gets result in Map<String, Map<String, Object>> summaryReport; and returns summaryReport.values()

Comment: Can you post how does your `someMethod()` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely because someMethod() returns a collection which you can't insert into. If it is a "Rread only" collection, then it will throw UnsupportedOperation on all insert/add calls.

Comment: It returns collection<Map<String,Object>> only.

Comment: I saw that. I updated my text to collection instead of map. But the point still stand. It returns a "Read only" collection to you.

Answer (score 0):

It must be an unmodifiable collection. It's impossible to say anymore without seeing the code for "someMethod()".

**edit**
Ok, check the API for Map.values()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()

Specifically this part.
*"The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does **not support the add or addAll operations**."*

Comment: someMethod gets result in   Map<String, Map<String, Object>> summaryReport;  and returns summaryReport.values()

Comment: I edited my answer based on your extra information about someMethod(). Not sure if you saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be there could be problem with someMethod(). I extend your example but it's working fine.

```
private static Collection<Map<String, Object>> someMethod() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("test", new Object());
        List list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(map);
        return list;
    }
    Collection<Map<String, Object>> xyz = someMethod();
    xyz.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is HashMap should have assign? else it will cause compile error.
such as

```
xyz.add(new HashMap<String,Object>());
```